How to change background color in an embedded Grafana panel in an iframe?
I know many people have asked how to change the background color of dashboards, where suggestions like using the Boom panel come up. However, if embedding a single panel in an iframe, this option is supposedly not viable as the Boom panel is part of a dashboard, not a panel alone.
Previously I have been able to edit the dark-theme css to change background color to black. However, after updating to a new version (11.1) those changes were lost and modifying the grafana.dark.ac9d572e376a8330bd1a.css  file under /usr/share/grafana/public/build/ no longer works - even after removing all dark grey background colors, the background color still gets overridden from body style, which I don't know where and how it is defined. How to get rid of the contrast-paling gray background in favor of fully black? Is there a way to define style in the panel json that would do the trick? I load the iframe from within javascript, so if possible to do change the background from there, that is also acceptable. In the browser inspect-window I can manually disable the body dark-theme gray background, but I am not sure if I could do it from code due to access limitations to the internals of the iframe.
I have difficulty understanding why the elementary need of getting a fully black background, which loads of people are requesting, is so difficult in a framework that is otherwise so versatile.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
